# Mapping for nullable property results in 0 but not Null

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nullable

I have the following mapping defined via FluentMapping

```
public class RuleMap : ClassMap<Rule>
{
    public RuleMap()
    {
        Table("NEW");

        Id(x => x.Id, "Id").Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.SenderId, "SenderId").Nullable();
    }
}
```

for the following class

```
public class Rule
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual int? SenderId { get; set; }
}
```

My Table in Database is defined as

```
USE [Test]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[NEW]    Script Date: 23.04.2015 22:14:53 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[NEW](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SenderId] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_NEW] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

and has a single Entry with

```
Id  | SenderId
 1  |  `NULL`
```

Now when I load all Rules via my SessionFactory

```
var rules = sessionFactory.QueryOvery<Rule>.List();
```

the list contains 1 Item (so far so good), but the property `SenderId` has the value **0** and **not NULL** what I have expected.

So what am I doing wrong here?

Using NHibernate 3.1 and FluentNHibernate 1.2.

Answer (score 3):

Change your mapping to,

```
public class NullableMap : ClassMap<Nullable>
{
    public NullableMap()
    {
        Table("nullable");
        LazyLoad();
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity().Column("id");
        Map(x => x.SenderId, "SenderId").Nullable().Default(null);
    }
}
```

where default value is set to null (`.Default(null);`)

Comment: thanks for your answer. My problem is solved now. Code and setup was all correct, but the value in the DB not. It was a little bit late yesterday.

Comment: Sorry, but no, you shouldn't need to declare a default value of null to get NULL in a nullable column. One possible exception could be if there is some mapping convention setting the default value - but I'm not sure such a thing could be overridden this way, and one could argue that it's the convention that is flawed and should be fixed instead.